# how enable curl's AsynchDNS?

Tags: php, curl, c-ares

I want enable curl's AsynchDNS ( find in phpinfo() ) . What do i must do ?
This is screenshot : 
[image]

I found out install http://c-ares.haxx.se/

```
c-ares is a C library that performs DNS requests and name resolves asynchronously
```

http://curl.haxx.se/dev/readme-ares.html
But i still stuck at how install on curl exist.

Comment: have you tried `ini_set(AsynchDNS,1)` or change the value inside the php.ini file

Comment: i don't think AsynchDNS exist in php.ini

Answer (score 4, accepted):

libcurl needs to have been compiled and built for it. For Linux and other *nix systems, you can build with c-ares or the threaded-resolver to make it use asynchronous resolves.