# Zend HttpClient more granular timeouts?

Tags: php, curl, zend-framework2

It seems as though ZendFramework2's various http client adapters allow connect and read timeouts in the seconds range; enforced by casting the various timeout parameters to (int) before setting them. In our organization, we typically specify smaller connection and read timeouts for production environments (we have a SOA in place).

However, the Socket-level functions in php support (float) values for timeouts to support sub-second timeouts, and there are means to support sub-second connect timeouts using libcurl since PHP 5.2.3.  (CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS with cURL complied with c-ares per [how enable curl's AsynchDNS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6012617/796064)).

I'm happy to enter a ticket to ZendFramework to support smaller, more granular timeouts but wanted to first see if this is a solved problem out here 'in the wild'. Has anyone gotten the Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Socket or \Curl adapters to support sub-second connect and read timeouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know two ways to tackle your problem. You can use the as a temporary fix until the Zend Framework 2 supports the sub-second timeout on it's own.

1. Override the `Socket`/`Curl` classes

   Create module and inherit from the `Socket` / `Curl` classes and override the `connect()` method to support sub-second timeout.

   For the `Curl` class I would add a new option `timeout_ms` in the configuration array, so you can still use the old `timeout` option. **My code only shows the relevant changes to the timeout section.**

   ```
   <?php
   use Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl;

   class CurlMs extends Curl 
   {

     public function connect($host, $port = 80, $secure = false)
     {
       ...
       // Replace the lines with timeout with the following lines.
       if (isset($this->config['timeout_ms'])) {
         // Set timeout milliseconds
         curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, $this->config['timeout_ms']);
       } elseif (isset($this->config['timeout'])) {
         // Set timeout
         curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $this->config['timeout']);
       }
       ...
     }
   }
   ```

   For the `Socket` class the situation is a little bit harder to solve, because of the different interfaces of `stream_socket_client()` and `stream_socket_timeout()`. The option `timeout` is now a float value. **As above I only included the relevant code parts.**

   ```
   <?php
   use Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Socket;

   class SocketMs extends Socket 
   {

     public function connectconnect($host, $port = 80, $secure = false)
     { 
      ...
       // Replace the lines with socket connect
       $this->socket = stream_socket_client(
         $host . ':' . $port,
         $errno,
         $errstr,
         (float) $this->config['timeout'],
         $flags,
         $context
       );
       ...
       // Replace the lines with stream timeout
       // get the fraction of the float value and convert it microseconds
       $fraction = ($this->config['timeout'] - floor($this->config['timeout'])) * 1000;
       // Set the stream timeout               
       if (!stream_set_timeout($this->socket, (int) $this->config['timeout'], (int) $fraction)  {                                      
         throw new AdapterException\RuntimeException('Unable to set the connection timeout');
       }
       ...
     }
   }
   ```
2. Patch the `Socket.php` / `Curl.php` files

   Write a patch for the files you where you want to add the sub-second timeout and apply them to your ZendFramework 2 version. You can automate the process with [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) if you use it. I created the patches against the [ZendFramework 2 version 2.3.3](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/release-2.3.3).

   **I wouldn't recommend this approach, because it has some pitfalls.**

   The patch for the `Curl.php` file would like the following:

   ```
   --- a/library/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Curl.php
   +++ b/library/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Curl.php
   @@ -200,7 +200,10 @@ class Curl implements HttpAdapter, StreamInterface
                curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_PORT, intval($port));
            }

   -        if (isset($this->config['timeout'])) {
   +        if (isset($this->config['timeout_ms'])) {
   +            // Set timeout milliseconds
   +            curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, $this->config['timeout_ms']);
   +        } elseif (isset($this->config['timeout'])) {
                // Set timeout
                curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $this->config['timeout']);
            }
   ```

   The patch for the `Socket.php` file would be like this:

   ```
   --- a/library/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Socket.php
   +++ b/library/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Socket.php
   @@ -247,7 +247,7 @@ class Socket implements HttpAdapter, StreamInterface
                    $host . ':' . $port,
                    $errno,
                    $errstr,
   -                (int) $this->config['timeout'],
   +                (float) $this->config['timeout'],
                    $flags,
                    $context
                );
   @@ -268,7 +268,9 @@ class Socket implements HttpAdapter, StreamInterface
                }

                // Set the stream timeout
   -            if (!stream_set_timeout($this->socket, (int) $this->config['timeout'])) {
   +            // get the fraction of the timeout and convert it to microseconds
   +            $fraction = ($this->config['timeout'] - floor($this->config['timeout'])) * 1000;
   +            if (!stream_set_timeout($this->socket, (int) $this->config['timeout'], (int) $fraction)) {
                    throw new AdapterException\RuntimeException('Unable to set the connection timeout');
                }
   ```