# Enable asynchDNS curl php

Tags: php, multithreading, curl

I am on a Debian wheezy and would like to speed up curl in php while doing a lot of DNS requests. asynchDNS seems like a good option to be enabled.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012617/how-enable-curls-asynchdns) has already been asked here and unfortunately it did not solve my problem. I indeed compiled curl with c-ares (and also tried with the threaded-resolver), following [curl.haxx.se](http://curl.haxx.se/dev/readme-ares.html) but it did not change the output of my `phpinfo` which still displays `asynchDNS => no`.

Also, while executing `./configure --enable-threaded-resolver` for curl, I get the confirmation `resolver: threaded` for the build of the program and don't see any changes afterwards.

Did anyone manage to have asynchDNS enabled and if so, how ?