# How to enable curl's AsynchDNS in info.php,

Tags: php, centos

I am using `centos 6`, I want to enable `curl's` `AsynchDNS`.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how enable curl's AsynchDNS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012617/how-enable-curls-asynchdns)

Comment: I need AsynchDNS = yes but currently  AsynchDNS = no

Comment: Correct. You'll have to recompile curl with the support.